# Python: Flask import failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on Apache using mod_wsgi. Im using a virtual environment. But the below line is failing.

```
from flask import Flask
```

Error:

```
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242] mod_wsgi (pid=6937): Target WSGI script '/var/www/sample_rest/sample_rest.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242] mod_wsgi (pid=6937): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/sample_rest/sample_rest.wsgi'.
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/sample_rest.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]  from sample_rest import sample_rest as application
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/sample_rest.py", line 2, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     from .serving import run_simple
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 51, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     from .exceptions import InternalServerError
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 68, in <module>
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     from .utils import escape
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]   File "/var/www/sample_rest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 189
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]     "area",
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]      ^ 
[Wed Sep 23 07:58:50 2020] [error] [client 10.192.73.242]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As you can see the error is within the code of flask itself. I'm using Python-3.6.2 which is supported by flask. The source code of flask in which it's showing error is also correct. What could be the issue ?

Comment: Which version of flask are you using?

Comment: I'm using flask-1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this rather then commenting:

Try to install Flask 1.1.1 which worked for me:

```
pip install Flask==1.1.1
```